# How to make a countdown timer?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, uwp, uwp-xaml

Hi I'm writing a Scoreboard UWP app and I would like to know how to make the code behind the timer. Because is a basketball scoreboard it has 2 clocks, one only for seconds (shotclock) and other that manages minutes and seconds.
So, I would like to know if there is an easy way to make this kind of countdowns in UWP.

I've just found this but it counts up not down:

```
    private void stopwatch_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_stopwatch.IsRunning)
        {
            _stopwatch.Stop();
            _timer.Dispose();
        }
        else
        {
            _stopwatch.Start();
            _timer = new Timer(updateTime, null, (int)TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1).TotalMinutes, Timeout.Infinite);
        }

    }

    private async void updateTime(object state)
    {
        await Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,
            () =>
                {

                    stopwatchLbl.Text = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}", _stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalMinutes, _stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds, _stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds / 10);

                    //stopwatchLbl.Text = "00:00:00";

                }
            );

    }
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Provide evidence of research...

Comment: Yes I've done a lot of research but I haven't found nothing for useful UWP, only timers that count up but not down...idk

Answer (score 0):

try this code , i wish that will help you :)

```
internal class countDownTimer
    {
        public int enlapsedTime;
        private DispatcherTimer dispatch;

        public delegate void MyCallback();
        public delegate void MyCallback2(int value);
        public MyCallback OnStartTime;
        public MyCallback OnStopTime;
        public MyCallback OnEndTime;
        public MyCallback2 OnCountTime;

        public countDownTimer()
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("StopWatch init");
            enlapsedTime = 0;
            dispatch = new DispatcherTimer();
            dispatch.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
            dispatch.Tick += timer_Tick;
        }

        private void timer_Tick(object sender, object e)
        {
            enlapsedTime--;
            Debug.WriteLine(enlapsedTime);

            if (OnCountTime != null) OnCountTime(enlapsedTime);

            if (enlapsedTime < 0)
            {
                enlapsedTime = 0;
                dispatch.Stop();
                if (OnEndTime != null) OnEndTime();
            }
        }

        public void Start()
        {
            dispatch.Start();
            if (OnStartTime != null) OnStartTime();
            Debug.WriteLine("iniciar contador");
        }

        public void Stop()
        {
            dispatch.Stop();
            if (OnStopTime != null) OnStopTime();
            Debug.WriteLine("parar contador");
        }

        public bool IsEnabled
        {
            get
            {
                return dispatch.IsEnabled;
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: `DispatcherTimer` runs on an UI thread so it's not much accurate.

Comment: Thanks this finally work for me adapting it to my UI instead of using Debug tools, it just work idk/idc about precision/accurate

Answer (score 0):

You may use the `UWPHelper.Utilities.ThreadPoolTimer` from my NuGet package [UWPHelper](https://www.nuget.org/packages/UWPHelper/). You will need to check the `Include pre-release` checkbox in NuGet Package Manager to be able to download it.

My `ThreadPoolTimer` is a wrapper class for `System.Threading.Timer` and it works similarly to the `DispatcherTimer` however it runs on the ThreadPool, not on the UI thread.

```
using UWPHelper.Utilities;

// TimeSpan indicates the interval of the timer
ThreadPoolTimer timer = new ThreadPoolTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
timer.Tick += OnTick;

void OnTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Method invoked on Tick - every second in this scenario
} 

// To start the timer
timer.Start();

// To stop the timer
timer.Stop();
```

Comment: I don't know how to do de part that says "// Invoked every second", I put the following code there `ShotClockText.Text = Convert.ToString(shotclocktime - 1);` and it only counts 1 down, not every second, pls help.

Comment: I'm can't make it work this way with my UI :( but finally works with the other answer, thanks anyway.

Comment: Oh, I finally make it work with this method, the problem was (shotclocktime - 1) now works using `shotclocktime--;` thanks :)